# Clear an InkCanvas [UWP]

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

I want to add a button to my UWP app that removes all the strokes from an `InkCanvas`, but the suggested method `inkCanvas.InkPresenter.Strokes.Clear()` isn't recognized as a valid command, is it obsolete or I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/pen-and-stylus-interactions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.Clear();`.

Comment: Cannot get to InkPresenter do to it's protection level

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on buttonclick:

```
YourCanvasName.Strokes.Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really worked until I coded this out:
This is on button click btw.

**YourWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void ClearBtn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(YourInkCanvaName.Strokes.Count != 0)
            {
                while (YourInkCanva.Strokes.Count > 0)
                {
                    draw.Strokes.RemoveAt(draw.Strokes.Count - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // DO NOTHING WHEN THERE IS NOTHING TO CLEAR
            }
            
        }
```